# need help for Imacros

Tags: imacros

please anybody can help me on my query. I am using Imacros. I want to extract from URL. last number of next page. the problem is when I run the url the next page number is just blink once. is there any solution where I can stop autojavascript and extract Laast Number

I dont know how to write code  here is the URL

http://www.justdial.com/Jamnagar/Architects/page-50

Here its shwo just once maximum page is 5 so I want to extract that (5) number.

[look in to IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IR8G5.jpg)

thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

use this command

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:sec-1<SP>col-sm-5<SP>hidden-xs EXTRACT=TXT
```